# Using NSImageView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created a class derived from NSImageView. However, the classes's constructor (init) is not being called, therefore I'm guessing init is not the correct initializer for NSImageView.

What is the correct initializer for NSImageView? I checked out the [manuals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but they don't seem to mention the correct init function. A google search doesn't seem to provide any concrete [results](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/115891-how-to-init-subclass-of-nsimageview.html) either.

I have found a *possible* constructor:

> -(id) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect

but I'm not sure if this would be the correct one to call. I'm not too sure what a frameRect is.

**What would be the default initializer/constructor for NSImageView?** Note I am developing a desktop app not an iOS app if that makes a difference.The NSImageView subclass object has been placed in the window through Interface Builder, not programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's from a nib/xib, initWithCoder:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If it's from a nib/xib"?

Comment: Look at the answer from @Riddler (and +1 to him).  NSImageViews can be created within user interface (xib or nib) files, in addition to being created programmatically.

Comment: I just tried it with a generic NSView subclass and initWithFrame gets called for me on 10.7, but not initWithCoder. Not sure why - I know in the past we had to override initWithCoder for some things, although awakeFromNib was used more often.

Comment: @EricS initWithCoder seems to work perfectly on my machine, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, when I try an NSImageView subclass rather than a direct NSView subclass it works here too. Computers are so strange sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

Classes derived from `NSView` can be initialised programmatically using `initWithFrame` or when loaded from a NIB file using `awakeFromNib`.  What I do is call a common, private, method to perform initialisation, regardless of how they were loaded:

```
// Private methods
@interface MyViewSubclass ()

- (void)_setupView;

@end

@implementation MyViewSubclass

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        [self _setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self _setupView];
}

// Common initialisation (called by initWithFrame: and awakeFromNib).
- (void)_setupView
{
    // Set stuff up
}
```